# Currency formatting on ComboBox items

Tags: wpf, combobox, converters

I have a ComboBox bound to an ObservableCollection of decimals.  What is the correct way to apply our currency converter to the items?

Edit:

a) I have an existing currency converter that I must use
b) .NET 3.0

Do I need to template the items?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your best bet if you have some code to do the conversion is indeed to run each item through an IValueConverter via a template.

```
<Window.Resources>
    <my:CurrencyConverter x:Key="currencyConverter" />

    <DataTemplate x:Key="thingTemplate" DataType="{x:Type my:Thing}">
        <TextBlock
            Text="{Binding Amount,Converter={StaticResource currencyConverter}}" />
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>

<ComboBox
    ItemSource="... some list of Thing instances ..."
    ItemTemplate="{StaticResource thingTemplate}" />
```

So you just define your CurrencyConverter class such that it implements IValueConverter and calls your code to turn the given amount into a formatted string.

Answer (score 10):

You can use the ItemStringFormat property on ComboBox to tell it how to format each of its items:

```
<ComboBox ItemStringFormat="c">
```

However, be aware that when using "c" as a currency formatter, it will use the currency defined by the local machine. If your values are defined in $ but your client PC is running with pounds or yen as their currency symbol, they won't be seeing what you want them to see.

Comment: We have a specific currency converter that we use and I do need to use that one.  Thanks though.

Comment: Yeah if you have code you need to call then an IValueConverter implementation is the best way.

Comment: But do I do that through an item template, and what is the correct way of setting the selected value?

Comment: Worked for me! This is exactly what I was looking for. I was just looking to format a Date and was trying with an IConverter and setting the StringFormat on the ItemsSource or other places. This did the trick after much Googling! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use **StringFormat** in the Binding expression like

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Value, StringFormat=Amount: {0:C}}"/>
```

See this [blog for more details.](http://blogs.msdn.com/llobo/archive/2008/05/19/wpf-3-5-sp1-feature-stringformat.aspx)

A [ValueConverter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.ivalueconverter.aspx) is another way - StringFormat doesnt work on .NET3.0 it needs WPF3.5 SP1.